# GroupingBy in java streams API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

input:

[image]

OutPut:
SessionId  TimeSpent
123        15
124        2

i have to calculate total time spent for each session.
I have tried below code for getting above output.

```
List<IsolatedTrafficPerSession> l  = new ArrayList();
        Map<String,Map<String,List<IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO>>> mapg = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO::getIsolateSessionId, Collectors.groupingBy(IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO::getIsolateTabId)));
        for(String sessionid: mapg.keySet()){
            int timeSpent  = 0;
            Map<String,List<IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO>> m = mapg.get(sessionid);
             for(String tabId: m.keySet()){
                 for(IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO isolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO: m.get(tabId)){
                     if(isolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO.getIsolateType() == 0) {
                         timeSpent = timeSpent+ isolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO.getCreatedTimestamp();
                     }
                    
                 }

             }
            IsolatedTrafficPerSession isolatedTrafficPerSession = new IsolatedTrafficPerSession();
             isolatedTrafficPerSession.setSession_id(sessionid);
             isolatedTrafficPerSession.setTimeSpent(timeSpent);
             l.add(isolatedTrafficPerSession);

        }`
```

But My code looks like it's taking O(n^3) time complexity. Is there any better solution to get above my out put.

Comment: Weak title. Edit to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of your own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077069/groupingby-in-java-streams-api ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupingBy in java streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077069/groupingby-in-java-streams-api)

Comment: No. Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

For you scenario, `GroupingBy` may be redundant. You can just collect the *dtos* to a `Map` and return the `values` collection.

**Code Snippet:**

```
public static Collection<IsolatedTrafficPerSession> groupBasedOnSessionId(List<IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO::getIsolateSessionId,
                       dto -> new IsolatedTrafficPerSession()
                               .setSession_id(dto.getIsolateSessionId())
                               .setTimeSpent(dto.getIsolateType() == 0 ? dto.createdTimestamp : 0),
                       ( v1, v2) -> v1.setTimeSpent(v1.getTimeSpent() + v2.getTimeSpent())))
               .values();
}
```

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO> input = Arrays.asList(
            new IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO("123", "0", 1, 0),
            new IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO("123", "1", 2, 0),
            new IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO("124", "0", 2, 0),
            new IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO("123", "0", 0, 10),
            new IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO("123", "1", 0, 5),
            new IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO("124", "0", 0, 2));

    Collection<IsolatedTrafficPerSession> result = groupBasedOnSessionId(input);
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output:**

```
123 15
124 2
```

---

*Note:*

1. Used fluent style setter for `IsolatedTrafficPerSession` as below.

   ```
   public IsolatedTrafficPerSession setSession_id(String sessionId) {
           this.sessionId = sessionId;
           return this;
       }
   ```
2. Constructor used for `IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO`:

   ```
   public IsolatedDetailQueryResponseDTO(String isolateSessionId, String isolateTabId, int isolateType, int createdTimestamp) {
          this.isolateSessionId = isolateSessionId;
          this.isolateTabId = isolateTabId;
          this.isolateType = isolateType;
          this.createdTimestamp = createdTimestamp;
      }
   ```